# Macbook Pro Display Corruption

Tags: display

My Macbook has recently been having intermittent display corruption issues.

I ran the hardware test by rebooting and holding `D` at startup but no error was detected.

Any idea what the issue is or what I can do to troubleshoot it?

**edit**:
The laptop generally sits on a stand and isn't closed or opened often. The display corruption has so far only occurred spontaneously, not while the lid is being moved.

**edit 2**: I have selected the "integrated only" option in gfxCardStatus but the issue continues.

**edit 3**: HDMI out does not get corrupted.

Battery life seems to be about 3 minutes before the machine shuts off.

Moving the lid or pressing around the hinge does not affect the corruption.

**edit 4**: vertical lines now appear intermittently while the display is relatively clear

**edit 5:**
The laptop has been freezing up completely while plugged in to HDMI

Macbook Pro 11,3

macOS 10.13.6

Comment: I'd suspect the ribbon cable. Does it sometimes change if you move the lid?

Comment: @Tetsujin I haven't been able to reproduce the issue by moving the lid, and so far haven't tried moving the lid while the issue is occurring. I will try moving the lid the next time the screen becomes corrupted.

Comment: So this is a Late 2013, 15-inch MBP with NVIDIA GPU? The discrete GPUs have been a frequent point of failure over the years. There are ways to disable the dGPU and only use the Intel integrated unit instead, which may be useful to test the cause.

Comment: @benwiggy It is a 15-inch MBP with Nvidia. `About this Mac` lists Mid 2014.
I've tried disabling the discrete GPU with gfxCardStatus. `About this Mac` lists the integrated graphics as active, as does the active gpu in gfxcardstatus although the gui of gfxCardStatus indicates that the discrete gpu menu option is selected for some reason. The issue has continued with this configuration.
Would this count as disabling the discreet gpu for the purposes of testing or is there something additional I could try?
screenshots have been attached to the question.

Comment: @Tetsujin moving the lid or pressing around the hinge did not affect the corruption the last time it occurred. HDMI out still works properly while the internal LCD is corrupted. I wasn't able to display the output from hardware diagnostics through the HDMI out port to test the machine while it was experiencing the issue however.

Answer (score 2):

From the look of it, you have a "cold solder joint" on your graphics processor (GPU) chip.

One way to help verify this is if it changes or goes away when you gently flex the case. If that causes the display to change, it is most certainly a cold solder joint, although if you're lucky, it might be a loose connector. But that's probably a long shot.

A top-rate Mac repair shop *should* be able to fix it. Talk to them and ask if they do "board-level repair." Apple  will probably just replace the entire board… and charge you accordingly.

Either way, it's a hardware problem, and will require a hardware fix.

Comment: If your hardware guy confirms "cold solder joint," please come back and mark this as "the answer!" TIA!